# What is perpose of iptables NAT configuration in cell_z1?

Tags: cloud-foundry, diego

When I ssh into cell_z1. then I can see these routing tables.

```
    $ sudo iptables -t nat -L

    Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    w--prerouting  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    w--prerouting  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

    Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    w--postrouting  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

    Chain w--instance-coiaggg2s3f (1 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             cell-z1-0.node.dc1.cf.internal  tcp dpt:60036 /* ac4154dd-a2bd-41d8-46bb-c5dfa3c8bfb2 */ to:10.254.0.6:8080
    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             cell-z1-0.node.dc1.cf.internal  tcp dpt:60037 /* ac4154dd-a2bd-41d8-46bb-c5dfa3c8bfb2 */ to:10.254.0.6:2222

    Chain w--instance-coiaggg2s3l (1 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             cell-z1-0.node.dc1.cf.internal  tcp dpt:60040 /* 74ab1082-7eca-4a09-7364-b266a23a7fdf */ to:10.254.0.2:8080
    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             cell-z1-0.node.dc1.cf.internal  tcp dpt:60041 /* 74ab1082-7eca-4a09-7364-b266a23a7fdf */ to:10.254.0.2:2222

    Chain w--postrouting (1 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    MASQUERADE  all  --  10.254.0.0/30       !10.254.0.0/30        /* executor-healthcheck-8946f5d6-063c-4bae-474d-0032f72b8fcb */
    MASQUERADE  all  --  10.254.0.4/30       !10.254.0.4/30        /* ef658bba-214d-4eef-5228-410e8e8aeb69 */
    MASQUERADE  all  --  10.254.0.8/30       !10.254.0.8/30        /* 3cb958eb-409a-4aa9-48f1-41bb6573ebc6 */
    MASQUERADE  all  --  10.254.0.12/30      !10.254.0.12/30       /* 9600ee8c-9e63-4682-bed3-b14767ea46d3 */
    MASQUERADE  all  --  10.254.0.16/30      !10.254.0.16/30       /* executor-healthcheck-eda5cee2-81be-4890-6d67-2a9f108d6dda */

    Chain w--prerouting (2 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    w--instance-coiaggg2s3f  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* ac4154dd-a2bd-41d8-46bb-c5dfa3c8bfb2 */
    w--instance-coiaggg2s3l  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* 74ab1082-7eca-4a09-7364-b266a23a7fdf */
```

Question is: What is the perpose of these destinations?
When I curl in cell_z1, it returns 301 error. So, I think it's removed.

- 10.254.0.6:8080
- 10.254.0.6:2222
- 10.254.0.2:8080
- 10.254.0.2:2222

But, it causes router returns 502 error in some pushed application when router-emitter mapped that application port to 60036, 60037, 60040, 60041

My environment:
Host OS : Ubuntu Server 16.10
VirtualBox : 5.0.32

```
    $ bosh -e bosh-lite releases
    Using environment '192.168.50.4' as client 'admin'

    Name               Version          Commit Hash
    cf                 254+dev.1*       80a8305a+
    cf-mysql           34.2.0+dev.1*    b8dcbe32
    cf-rabbitmq        222.15.0+dev.1*  377afa0a+
    cf-rabbitmq-test   0.1.7            98720fb8
    cflinuxfs2-rootfs  1.60.0*          0b44b228+
    diego              1.11.0+dev.1*    4ee830c6
    garden-runc        1.4.0*           60f9e9dd
    routing            0.147.0          255f268f
    ~                  0.136.0          d29132da+
```

**UPDATED 4/11/2017**

I have found that this information comes from the Kawasaki (Guardian's Network Library). 
I see route table below. But Unlike 10.254.0.6, The route table does not have virtual NIC and route for 10.254.0.2 (10.254.0.0/30)

```
    $ route
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
    default         10.244.16.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0   0   wcl8gbnff7q4-1
    10.244.16.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0   0   wcl8gbnff7q4-1
    10.254.0.4      *               255.255.255.252 U     0      0   0   wbrdg-0afe0004
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deploy an application to CF, it runs in a container on one of your Diego Cells.  The container is given an internal port, at the moment this will always be 8080 with Diego, and the Cell publishes an external port (to the GoRouters).  The external port is mapped to the internal port with an iptables rule on the Cell.  I believe that is what you're seeing / asking about.

In summary, traffic takes a path like this from your browser to the app in the container:

```
Browser -> HTTP(S) -> Load Balancer -> HTTP(S) -> GoRouter -> (HTTP) -> External Port on Cell -> iptables -> Internal Port in Container -> Application
```

You might also be wondering about port 2222, this is similar but the port is used for `cf ssh` traffic into the container.

A layperson should **never** manually remove or adjust any of the iptables rules on a Diego Cells.